# Custom Resource for Chip inside SingleField [react-admin]

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a `building` resource which has `department`. When I click on the department chip, I want to edit the department. Currently, on GET /building, my API returns a data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Building 1",
    "departments: [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Department 1"},
      {"id": 1, "name": "Department 1"}
    ]
  }
]
```

When listing the buildings, I am able to the departments as `ChipField`s using the code below. But when I click on the department chips, I can not figure out a way to open the department edit form.

```
export const BuildingList = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="title" />
      <ArrayField source="departments">
        <SingleFieldList>
          <ChipField source="name"/>
        </SingleFieldList>
      </ArrayField>
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
}
```

[image: Department Chips while listing buildings]

Currently, clicking on the department opens URL like http://localhost:5000/api/building/%7B%22id%22:108,%22name%22:%22Dept.%20of%20Computer%20Science%22,%22url%22:%22http://www.southeastern.edu/acad_research/depts/comp_sci/%22,%22phone%22:%22985-549-2189%22,%22email%22:null,%22description%22:null,%22keywords%22:null,%22buildingId%22:1%7D

This means React-Admin thinks that this is a building, not a department. Any idea on how to get this working? Thank you.

This is the BulidingList to show

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem.  While apparently undocumented, `<ArrayField>` takes `basePath` as a property.

While not tested with your data, something like this might work for you, assuming `departments` is also a react-admin resource. This seems to configure the link automatically created for the ChipField.  In addition to specifying the `basePath`, I also specified the `fieldKey`, which is [documented](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#common-field-props).

```
<ArrayField basePath="/departments" source="departments" fieldKey="id">
  <SingleFieldList>
    <ChipField source="name" />
  </SingleFieldList>
</ArrayField>
```